# laravel use multiple database, query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I can't find the way  connect multiple db and chain sql query,

How to use raw mysql syntax?

```
$id = DB::connection('mysql1')->select(DB::raw('INSERT INTO article_category (name) VALUES (:name)'), array(
    'name' => $name
));  // did I do something wrong this not work..
```

How to use laravel method?

```
$id = DB::connection('mysql1')->table('article_category')->insertGetId(
    array(
        'name' => $name
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do raw this way:

```
DB::connection('mysql1')
    ->statement(
         DB::raw('insert into article_category (name) values (?)'),
         array($name)
    );
```

To get the Id after an insert this is a way:

Create a model for your table:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {}
```

And create a record on your table selecting a particular connection connection:

```
$post = Post::on('connectionName')->create($arrayOfvalues);

echo $post->id;
```

Comment: thanks for reply! I want to know both.

Comment: Edited to provide some more information on it.

Comment: did I do something wrong with  `DB::connection('mysql1')->select(DB::raw('INSERT INTO article_category (name) VALUES (:name)'), array(
    'name' => $name
));` it is not work

Comment: Laravel uses positional `?` as query parameters so its `VALUES (?)`

Comment: when I use this it will show error but it actually store success `DB::connection('mysql1')->select(DB::raw('INSERT INTO article_category (name) VALUES (:name)'), array('name' => $name ));` but when I change to `DB::connection('mysql1')->select(DB::raw('INSERT INTO article_category (name) VALUES (?)'), array('name' => $name ));` there's no error message but not store to database successful it is empty array

Comment: Odd, but try statement, edited to show how.

Comment: if I use ? still not work store to database, but I change to :value it work and don't have error.. wondering what is statement() difference select()?